# F# signature files - defining constructor parameters

Tags: f#

I'm running into an error when creating a signature file for an F# script file which I can't quite work out.

To replicate, create a new F# class library and add a file, Test.fs:

```
namespace Signatures

open System

type Test (id : Guid, name : string) =

  member this.Id = id
  member this.Name = name
```

This will build fine. Then create a new signature file above it, Test.fsi:

```
namespace Signatures

open System

type Test =

  new : (Guid * String) -> Test

  member Id : Guid
  member Name : String
```

This will now not build with the error `Module 'Signatures' requires a value 'new : (Guid * String) -> Test` (this is different to the error you get if the constructor signature is different in the two files). The only real documentation I can find on defining constructors in the signature file is [MSDN](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CGwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fdd233196.aspx&ei=yccWUPvSGKG_0QWc6YHADw&usg=AFQjCNGGGl5ofgFpxOv3oKq5pKxJmi_t2A&sig2=ghMSn3uXtlBzR0B-nlHiTA) and that deals with parameterless constructors.

If you hover over Test in the .fs file the constructor's signature matches the one in the .fsi file. I've also tried changing the constructor so that it is not implicit with no joy.

I'm using the VS2012 RC, and have tried .Net 4 and 4.5.

Comment: Pad's answer is good.  Note that you can use the `--sig` compiler flag to see what signatures would correspond to F# source files, though that's not exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's too long for a comment, so I post it as an answer.

`Test`'s constructor receives two arguments as its parameters, not one argument which is a tuple. I admit that `*` between arguments looks confusing. But the signature `Guid -> string -> Test` is even worse than that. Constructors should get some inputs and produce a new type instance. Curried form and partial application don't make sense in the context of constructors.

I think the brackets help clarify here.

```
type Test (id : System.Guid, name : string) =
  member this.Id = id
  member this.Name = name
```

produces `new : id:Guid * name:string -> Test` while

```
type Test (tuple: System.Guid * string) =
  let id, name = tuple
  member this.Id = id
  member this.Name = name
```

gives me `new : tuple:(Guid * string) -> Test` in an FSI session. I use F# 2.0/MonoDevelop 3.0 for the record.

Regarding creating type signatures, I usually send code into F# Interactive and copy produced signatures to `fsi` files to avoid mistakes. If the tooltips and F# Interactive show type signatures wrongly on VS2012 RC, you should report at fsbugs (at) microsoft (dot) com.

Answer (score 3):

An extra pair of parens can be significant. Consider the following:

```ml
type T =
  static member Add(x, y) = x + y
  static member AddTuple((x, y)) = x + y
```

which, in C#, appear as

```cs
int Add(int x, int y)
int AddTuple(Tuple<int, int> arg)
```

Tangentially, you can't do something similar in a constructor:

```ml
type Test((id, name)) = class end //DOESN'T COMPILE
```

Since constructors already take arguments in tupled form you would expect `'a * 'b` and `('a * 'b)` to be different things. This is consistent with method syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to explain why this works, I'd love to know but I just started fiddling with the syntax to see if I could get anything more revealing out of the compiler.

If I remove the brackets are the tuple, it compiles, i.e. change this:

```
new : (Guid * String) -> Test
```

To:

```
new : Guid * String -> Test
```

Comment: Test's constructor receives two arguments as its parameters, not one argument which is a tuple. It's similar to constructors of discriminated unions. It's just `*` between arguments makes type signatures look confusing.

Comment: I always thought constructor arguments were passed as tuples. If it were two arguments should the constructor signature be Guid -> String -> Test, as it would be for a function receiving two arguments? The tooltip on both the .fs and .fsi versions show it as new: (Guid * String) -> Test, just for added confusion.